# t-sql decimal assignment changes value

Tags: t-sql, decimal

Why does the select statement below return two different values ?

```
declare @tempDec decimal
set @tempDec = 1.0 / (1.0 + 1.0)
select @tempDec, 1.0 / (1.0 + 1.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fine for literals like 1.0, but if you're pulling the data from table columns, you need to cast/convert the first evaluated number in your equation:

```
convert(decimal, [col1]) / ([col2] + [col3])
```

-or-

```
convert(decimal(15, 2), [col1]) / ([col2] + [col3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out from a coworker just as I posted this.

You need to specify the default precision and scale.

This works in this scenario:
declare @tempDec decimal(3,2)

From MSDN:

decimal[ (p[ , s] )] and numeric[ (p[ , s] )] 
Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1. The SQL-92 synonyms for decimal are dec and dec(p, s). numeric is functionally equivalent to decimal.

p (precision) 
The maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.

s (scale) 
The maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

Comment: That is, zero scale in the local variable is removing the data after the point on storage